# Angular Routing & Nginx Re-write Issue

Tags: angular, nginx

We are running angular on Nginx for an application we are about to launch. Angular is using its routing functionality, so by default, if one were to refresh the page, Nginx returns a 404 error as it can't find the routed path.

To correct this, we have added the following section to the Nginx configuration:

```
location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
        }
```

This is working, to the degree that if you perform a browser refresh, then the page now partially loads. The issue is that the paths for various assets are being distorted.

For example, we have a path on the site called Account/Login which is accessed like so:

```
http://site.name/Account/Login
```

That page has a CSS file located within the assets folder. Normally when accessing the page completely through Angular routing (i.e. no refresh re-write), it would be located here:

```
http://site.name/Assets/CSS/Login.css
```

What we are finding is that when the page is refreshed, and re-written, whilst it loads, the asset path distorts and becomes:

```
http://site.name/Account/Login/Assets/CSS/Login.css
```

I suspect that this has nothing to do with Nginx and is, in fact, some configuration needed on the Angular side that will specify how the paths are referenced, but we are pretty new to Angular, so not sure where to start.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you manage to solve this. i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in Nginx Config file

```
   location / {
       index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
   }
```

Comment: Nginx service won't start with that configuration in place